# Optimize spark partition query

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Is there a better way to write this query... considering millions of rows using spark and hadoop

```sql
select *
from (
SELECT *, row_number() over(PARTITION BY tran_id ORDER BY load_dt DESC) RN
FROM MySourceTable WHERE CAST(tradeDtae) as TIMESTAMP) 
BETWEEN add_months(current_timestamp(), -64) AND current_timestamp() 
AND sys_id = 'TRADING
) temp where temp.RN=1;
```

MySourceTable is partioned by `tradeDtae` as int

query is running for hours on end and failing to 
return rows that satisfy the query

Answer (score 0):

Partition pruning may not work because function is applied to the tradeDtae column. Try to do it without function at all. And also cast(timestamp) does not work as you expect in Hive, consider the following example:

```
hive> select unix_timestamp(current_timestamp);
OK
1562741499
Time taken: 0.739 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select cast(1562741499 as timestamp);
OK
1970-01-18 18:05:41.499
Time taken: 0.191 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select current_timestamp;
OK
2019-07-09 23:53:07.662
Time taken: 1.482 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Correct method of converting **bigint** unix timestamp to timestamp is using from_unixtime:

```
hive> select from_unixtime(1562741499);
OK
2019-07-09 23:51:39
Time taken: 0.12 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

I suggest to calculate parameters separately as unix timestamps and pass as a parameters if partition pruning does not work with this query, try this first:

```
FROM MySourceTable 
WHERE tradeDtae BETWEEN unix_timestamp(add_months(current_timestamp(), -64),'yyyy-MM-dd') AND unix_timestamp()
```